# Adicionar shortcut a um menu em tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como adicionar um *shortcut* ao item dum menu. Já tive a procurar e vi que se pode fazer usando uma função especial e comum a todos os widgets do modulo `tkinker`, ou seja a função `bind`.

O que tentei fazer foi isto:

```
menu_file.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitf, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
menu_file.bind("<Control-Q>", exitf)
```

onde `exitf` é uma função que fecha a aplicação.

Mas sinceramente não percebi exatamente como funciona esta função `bind` ou a outra que se chama `bind_all`.

O que percebi  foi que o primeiro parâmetro é o evento e o segundo é o handler, poderiam explicar-me melhor e mais detalhadamente como funcionam ou indicar-me um bom site onde possa estudar isso?

Answer (score 1):

A maneira como resolvi este problema foi conectando a *função handler* com o *evento*, no meu caso `<Control-Q>`, chamando a função `bind_all` da *root* `Tk` da minha aplicação, e não chamando a função *bind* do menu directamente.

Se `master` é um objecto de tipo `Tk`, este é simplesmente um exemplo:

```
master.bind_all("<Command-q>", quit_application)
```

Para mais informações sobre os *eventos* e *bindings* em *Python* veja [aqui](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).